# How to apply the reset filter in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
//here we crate the module for the CRUD application here    
var app= angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myCont", function($scope,myService){

$scope.user =[];
$scope.one = [];

 //here we create the myService function for show the Dmmt array 
       $scope.user = myService.show();
       console.log($scope.user);

       //here we create the saveUser function for push the item into the list
  $scope.saveUser = function(){
   var data = 
     {
      eid:$scope.user.eid,
      email:$scope.user.email,
      city:$scope.user.city,
      salary:$scope.user.salary,
      date:$scope.user.date,
     } 
     console.log(data);
   //here we create will pass the user data to the myService of the show2 
   $scope.user =myService.show2(data);
    //Here we clear the form data with the help of the id
   document.getElementById("clear").reset();
   
    //Here we clear the form data without function
    // $scope.user.eid ="";
    // $scope.user.email ="";
    // $scope.user.city ="";
    // $scope.user.salary ="";
    // $scope.user.date ="";*/
     }
      
  //Calling setParam function  for the particular userDetails.
  
     $scope.setParam = function(index){
      $scope.one = $scope.user[index];
      console.log($scope.one);
     }

  //here we delete the deleteUser function for remove  the item into the lsit
  $scope.deleteUser = function(index) {
    $scope.result3 =myService.show3(index);
     console.log($scope.result3);

   }//close contrller here

   $scope.clearFilter =function() {
    $scope.user= "";

   }
});
//Declare the services
//her e we crete the myService function in which we declare the static that will be display in the 
//index.html page
app.service("myService",function(){

 var employee =[];
 var message="";

 //here we create the show function for declare dynamic array & display in the home page of the user
 this.show = function(){
  employee =
   [

    {
     eid:"Kapil sssssss",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:12000,
     city:"Indore",
     date:"2014-10-19",
     img:"./images/download.png"
   },
            
    {
     eid:"pooooo",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:5000,
     city:"Us",
     date:"2014-10-28",
    img:"../images/user.jpg"
   },
      {
     eid:"ddsa",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:120,
     city:"Bhopal",
     date:"2014-10-24",
    img:"./images/avtar.jpg" 
     },
      {
     eid:"dsaddaPotter",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:1000,
     city:"Agar-malwa",
     date:"2014-10-29",
    img:"./images/images.jpg"
   },
      {
     eid:"sadadasdasdasdsadsads54454",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:25000,
     city:"Indore",
     date:"2014-10-10",
    img:"./images/WP_16 September 2015_qstore.jpg"
   },
      {
     eid:"Gotm Potter",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:2000,
     city:"Playboy",
     date:"2014-10-03",
    img:"./images/download (1).png"      
     },
      {
     eid:"Harry a4644464654s Potter",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:35000,
     city:"Agar",
     date:"2014-10-19",
     img:"./images/download.png"
   },
            
    {
     eid:"mMayank rawal",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:5000,
     city:"Ujjain",
     date:"2014-10-28",
    img:"../images/user.jpg"
   },
      {
     eid:"Gotm Soni",
     email:"gotm@yahoo.com",
     salary:2000,
     city:"Dewas",
     date:"2014-10-24",
    img:"./images/avtar.jpg" 
     },
      {
     eid:"Deepsh thakur",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:12000,
     city:"Australia",
     date:"2014-10-29",
    img:"./images/images.jpg"
   },
      {
     eid:"Peter Potter",
     email:"harry@yahoo.com",
     salary:5000,
     city:"Harmaini",
     date:"2014-10-10",
    img:"./images/WP_16 September 2015_qstore.jpg"
   },
      {
     eid:"kapil Soni",
     email:"kapil@yahoo.com",
     salary:2000,
     city:"Playboy",
     date:"2014-10-03",
    img:"./images/download (1).png"      
     }
     ]
   return employee;

 }

 //here we create the show2 function that will be received our data from the contoller
 //& the push into the array of the employee
 this.show2 = function(data){
  employee.push(data);
  message="push ho gy";
  return employee;
 }

 //here we create the show3  function that will be remove user from the list
 //& through the index of the list
 this.show3 = function(index){
  employee.splice(index,1); }


}

);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <!-- include the angularjs files here-->
      <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app/controller.js"></script>
      <script src="app/service.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
 individual files as needed -->
      
  </head>
<body ng-controller="myCont">
  <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add New User</button>
          <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='ok.type1' data-ng-true-value="'Bhopal'" data-ng-false-value=''/>Bhopal
          <br>
          <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='ok.type2' data-ng-true-value="'Indore'" data-ng-false-value=''/> Indore<br>
          <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='ok.type3' data-ng-true-value="'Ujjain'" data-ng-false-value=''/>Ujjain
          <br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model='ok.type4' data-ng-true-value="'London'" data-ng-false-value=''/>London<br>
          <select ng-model="search">  
            <option value="Bhopal">Bhopal</option>
            <option value="London">London</option>
            <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
        </select>
         <button  class="btn btn-succes btn-md pull-right" id="clear-filter"  ng-click="clearFilter()" type="button">Clear Filter</button>
         <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   
      <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-info" ng-if="message">
          Info<a href="#" class="close" ng-click="clear()">&times;</a>.
      </div>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
               <th>User</th>
                <th>EmployeenName</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Date</th>              
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr ng-repeat="x in filtered =(user | filter:search) | filter:ok.type1 | filter:ok.type2 |  filter:ok.type3 |  filter:ok.type4 | orderBy:'salary' " 
           onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"
             ng-click ="setParam($index)">
                <td style="max-height:61px;"><img src={{x.img}}></img></td>
                <td>{{x.eid}}</td>
                <td>{{x.email}} </td>
                <td>{{x.salary| currency}}</td>
                <td>{{x.city}}</td>
                <td>{{x.date | date:'dd/mm/yy'}}</td>
                
          <div style="float:right; margin-top:8px;">  
              Total Count after Filtered-{{filtered.length}}</p>
          </div>
          <td>
              <button type="button"  class="btn btn-info" ng-click="isEditForm=true;">edit</button>
           </td>
           <td ng-show="isEditForm">
              <lable>Name</label><input ng-model="x.eid"/><br>
              <lable>Email</label><input ng-model="x.email"/><br>
              <lable>salary</label><input ng-model="x.salary"/><br>
              <lable>city</label><input ng-model="x.city"/><br>
              <lable>date</label><input ng-model="x.date"/><br>
                <button ng-click="isEditForm=false;">SAVE HERE</button>
             </td>
          <td>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div> 
      <!-- Modal -->
    //here we will provide the id for clear data 
      <form name="newUser" id="clear"  class="user" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4  class ="UpperText" class="modal-title"  >New User Registration</h4>
           </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Name</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="eid" ng-model="user.eid" placeholder="Enter Name" ng-minlength ="3" ng-maxlength="5">
                       <span class="danger" ng-show="newUser.eid.$touched && newUser.eid.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter EId</span>
                       <span  class="danger" ng-show="newUser.eid.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Enter min 3 digits.</span>
                   
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Email</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"  ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
                          <span class="danger" ng-show="newUser.email.$touched && newUser.email.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter Email</span>
                  </div>
              </div>
                             
         <div class="form-group">
            <label  class="control-label col-sm-2" style="white-space: nowrap;">Select Country:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select class="form-control countries" ng-model="user.city" id="countryId sel1">
                    <option value="">Select City</option>
                    <option value="Indore">Indore</option>
                    <option value="Bhopal">Bhopal</option>
                    <option value="Ujjain">Ujjain</option>
                  </select>
           </div>

             <!--  <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-2">City</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city" ng-model="user.city" placeholder="Enter city">
                     <span class="danger" ng-show="newUser.city.$touched && newUser.city.$pristine" class="help-block">
                      <span>Enter City</span>    
                  </div>
              </div> -->
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Salary</label>
                   <div class="col-sm-10">
                         <input type="number" class="form-control" name="salary" ng-model="user.salary" placeholder="Enter salary">
                         <span class="danger" ng-show="newUser.salary.$touched && newUser.salary.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter Salary</span> 
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Date</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" ng-model="user.date" placeholder="Enter date">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group"> 
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default"  data-dismiss="modal"
                  ng-click="saveUser()"  ng-disabled="newUser.$invalid" > 
             </div>
                </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                  </div>
                </div>
             
            </div> <!-- here model body is closed-->
          </div> <!-- here model content is clo  sed-->
       </form>
      <!-- Declare another model is declare for edit Modal -->
      <!--Here we creat the delete user model for dlete the user -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModalDelete" role="dialog">
         <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header"> 
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;
                      </button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Are R Want to Delete </h4>
                  </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <strong style="color:blue;">
                          You re going to delete the {{one.eid}}</strong>
                      </h4>
                  </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="deleteUser($index)">Yes
                      </button>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                </div>
               </div> <!-- here model body is closed-->
          </div> <!-- here model content is closed-->
        </div>
<div class="w3-container">
  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-8 w3-animate-left" style="max-width:600px">
      <div class="w3-center"><br>
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-closebtn w3-hover-red w3-container w3-padding-8 w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        <img src="{{one.img}}" alt="Avatar" class="w3-circle w3-margin-top">

      </div>
      <form class="w3-container" action="form.asp">
         <div class="table-responsive">    
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>Date</th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
              <td>{{one.eid}}</td>
              <td>{{one.email}}</td>
              <td>{{one.salary}}</td>
              <td>{{one.city}}</td>
              <td>{{one.date}}</td>
               <span class="btn btn-info"><a href="https://angularjs.org/" target="_self">Follow Here</a></span>
        </table>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

    </body>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) --
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

I have to apply the filter with checkbox in such case checkbox filter is working properly  and list is properly filtered but  after that i have click on the   Reset button to reset all the JSON data but in my case all data is cleared how to do this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a deep copy of your data and then on hitting reset reassign it.

```
angular.copy(source, [destination]);
```